# Upload contact image in AWS S3

Tags: contact-image

Is it possible to upload contact images to an AWS S3 bucket?

My list of contacts is too big to store all the images in my current server so I was thinking that it would be great if I could store all the contact images in AWS S3.

I am already doing it but I have to use a custom portal with custom code to take a photo from a webcam, resize it, upload it to S3, get that URL and add it in civiCRM database. It would be great to be able to do everything in CiviCRM but it would be a great start just to upload files in AWS S3